# How to use dbt_utils.union_relations in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, dbt-utils

I have the following code:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='table',
        unique_key='dbt_scd_id'
    )
}}

with unioned as (
  {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
    relations=[
      ref('blaze_inventory_stg'),
    ],
    include=[
      "source_name",
      "location_id_ext",
      "product_name",
      "brand",
      "strain_name",
      "category",
      "product_weight_grams",
      "product_unit_of_measure",
      "purchase_category",
      "quantity",
      "sku",
      "dbt_updated_at",
      "dbt_valid_from",
      "dbt_valid_to",
      "dbt_scd_id"
    ]
  )}}
)

select * from unioned
```

It produces this sql

```
      create or replace transient table POS_DATA.dbt_dev.retail_inventory_snapshot_stg  as
      (

with unioned as (
  

        (
            select

                cast('POS_DATA.dbt_dev.blaze_inventory_stg' as 
    varchar
) as _dbt_source_relation,
                

            from POS_DATA.dbt_dev.blaze_inventory_stg
        )

        
)

select * from unioned
      );
```

Clearly its not getting all of the column names from that table and inserting them. Why is this? I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727772/using-dbt-utils-union-relations-wrong-but-dont-know-how-why) that the dbt_utils.union_relation relies on the information schema to build its query. Perhaps snowflakes information schema is undiscoverable by dbt?

Comment: 1. do you already have `dbt_utils` installed as a package? 2. what happens if you remove (temporarily) the config block? 3. why are you only trying to union one relation?

Comment: I do have dbt_utils installed as a package via the packages.yml version 0.7.4 from dbt-labs. If I remove the conflig block it generates the same exact query. I originally had more models that I was unioning and removed those. Perhaps I should just skip this unioning then and just select those columns from this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem - or what seems to be the same problem, also using DBT on Snowflake.

In my case, I had not quoted the columns when creating the sources, so the case was Snowflake default (uppercase). This doesn't match the include list since it is all lowercase.

So, I my case, I first removed the include list (created a copy of the source table). That worked.

Then I tried the include list, but upper cased, and voila - it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the macro is failing to fetch the column names from the relations you're naming ([macro source code](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/union.sql)) As to why I'm not sure. Have you called `dbt run -m blaze_inventory_stg` already?

To prove my hypothesis, make a new model file, `big_boy.sql` with the following code, then run `dbt run -m big_boy`. My guess is that the columns won't resolve.

```sql
-- big_boy.sql
{% if execute %}
  {%- set cols = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(ref('blaze_inventory_stg')) -%}
  {{ log('colums: ' ~ cols, info=True) }}
{% endif %}

SELECT 1 as my_col
```

If the above model file does indeed fetch and print the columns to the console, then something else is going on. To further debug, I'd recommend renaming the `default__union_relations` macro linked above to a new name, then invoking the new macro in your model. Then you can intersperse `log` statements to get more information about where exactly things are going wrong.

Comment: Those columns do resolve properly from that template,  however they are uppercased by snowflake, something which I had forgotten and which @Erik pointed out in his answer.